# Globalizing runtime generated assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, resources, globalization

### **Background**

A project installs some files that contain all the elements to define a UserControl - some user source, a CodeCompileUnit for designer code, and a resx file. At runtime, these files are compiled into an assembly and the classes are consumed by our main application (the assembly is only updated when necessary).

### **Question**

The project has to be globalized and as part of that process, there is a need to provide localizations of these files. Two options are either to allow the inclusion of additional resx files for different locales (either within the same files or as additional side-by-side files) that can be compiled into a satellite assembly for the main assembly, or to provide a copy of each full file for each supported language, compiling the appropriate set for the language being supported.

- Does anyone have any other options that might be worth considering?
- What problems might be inherent in either of the solutions I've proposed?

---

***Constraints/Disclaimer***
I am aware that the scenario is less than ideal and that better choices could've been made in some areas (like globalizing from the start), but they cannot be changed at this point in the project. I appreciate any advice, solutions, or leads you can provide. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a separate satellite assembly for each culture. This has two benefits:

- You can build all of the assemblies in one go, and have a definitive file for each version number and filename combination, rather than it *also* depending on the culture.
- You can have multiple assemblies in the same installation, and base the language to use on the system language, or a user preference etc. This will make development and testing significantly easier, as you won't need to keep rebuilding and copying files around just for the sake of changing languages.
- It's how .NET i18n is designed to work. While I'm not an expert on .NET i18n ("read Guy Smith-Ferrier's book" is my best advice!) I generally find that frameworks work best when you follow their expected model.

Even if the final part of "building the satellite assembly" is done at runtime (can you do it at *install* time instead?) you still get the second and third bullet advantages at least. It also means that if you ever *do* go the more normal route of supplying the satellite assemblies to start with (instead of building them on the user's box) you'll have less to change.

Apologies if I've misunderstood the question though...

Comment: I am certainly doing all I can to leverage the way .NET wants to work. Our file format somewhat hinders this and I have to come up with a process that doesn't require a full rewrite. Currently, my thinking is very similar to yours: have resx files for each language and build a per language satellite

Comment: ...assembly. I would love to do the build on install, but we have certain requirements to refresh the assemblies at application start-up, so this isn't currently possible.

The framework for distributing and selecting a language is in place for the remainder of the application, using .NET support...

Comment: ...wherever possible. The main difference for this problem is how we distribute the additional localizations. My current thinking is to ship the resx in some encrypted format (to prevent tampering). The format would also need versioning to match with the main file.

Comment: Yup - that means your period of "not doing the normal thing" part is as short as possible.

Comment: While this covers the deployment/integration of localisations, I have one additional issue. Our panels are created by a designer that we have written, and I haven't been able to get the Localizable extension property to appear that forces the designer to put localizable values into resources. Ideas?

Comment: No, I don't know anything about that I'm afraid... I suspect you'll be best off asking a new question for that one, to gain more knowledgeable readers :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not planning on adding additional languages after deployment (at least not without a software update), then I'd favor compiling all the additional RESX files into a satellite assembly that you include. That way, they're not user editable once they're deployed.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good suggestion although from recent discussions, it looks like we will want to add languages after deployment. That said, your suggestion may well still work as we could re-deploy any satellite assemblies whenever we add a language.